# DateTime::createFromFormat creating an error

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, datetime-format

This snippet of code is causing a glitch in my site. If they do not fill out the date field I have created in advanced custom fields the page breaks and i'm get a php error.

Here is my code but i can not seem to get it fixed.

```
<?php $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_date')); ?>
<h3><?php echo $date->format('F j, Y'); ?></h3>
```

Comment: show `echo get_field('event_date'));`

Comment: @KrisRoofe presumably it's `null` or an empty string.

Comment: What should the `$date` be if they do not fill out the date field?

Comment: @Phil the date should just be empty at that point if they do not have a date.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you just need to cater for empty / `null` values. For example, if the fallback / default date should be *now*...

```
$dateString = get_field('event_date');
$date = !empty($dateString)
    ? DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $dateString) : new DateTime();
```